# Order of a subgroup given a function

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = \langle g\rangle$, $|G| = pq$ with $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, and define $\varphi: x \mapsto  x^q$ for $x \in G$. Show that $|\varphi(G)| = p$.

I'm not sure how to do this; does it have anything to do with the order of an element being a factor of either $p$ or $q$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Prove that $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism (you will need to use the fact that $G$ is abelian), and use the first isomorphism theorem. The fact that $G$ is cyclic will help you determine $\ker \varphi$.